# Localization issue in list of all sites

Tags: bug, localization

On the list of [all sites on the Stack Exchange page,](https://stackexchange.com/sites) the non-English Stack Overflow sites do not have a properly localized description

[image]
[image]

The Russian one should read as

> Сайт вопросов и ответов для программистов

The Portuguese one should read as

> Site de perguntas e respostas para programadores profissionais e entusiastas

I don't know Japanese, so I don't know what it should look like.